# All my new questions are suddenly downvoted

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

For the last 2 days, my questions were downvoted. I have no idea what's wrong with them. I showed them to my colleagues and they also think that they are fine.

How can I deal with it?

Comment: Opinion based and no effort. I'm not an Android developer, but found an answer to the question about adaptive icons.

Comment: Sorry, but disagree. I made the mockup only for the question. And I know, what are adaptive icons, it's not a problem to find. The problem is how to create the rainbow background in xml and backward compatibility.

Comment: Quote: "the problem is..."  And yet the question does not mention that at all.  Very bad idea.

Comment: Google is your friend, [use it](https://www.google.com/search?q=backward+compatible+android+icons&oq=backward+compatible+andorid+icons). Anyway, it's unclear what you're asking in the question. No details.

Comment: Those two questions were down-voted because there weren't really  good for SO, **and you were unlucky and those questions were noticed**. You did ask a couple or more questions that were similar to these two: and yet you where you were luckier got a better off. That might have made you think (wrongly) that type of question was acceptable in the network.

Comment: @qbait, you seem to have [reposted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736914/how-to-create-the-multicolor-gradient-background-as-xml) one of the questions you've [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49735437/how-to-create-instagram-launcher-icon), almost verbatim. That is not something you should do. And that is still a poor question, even if not primarily opinion based.

Comment: I made it much more specific.

Comment: I have no idea, why I'm getting downvotes again. I'm asking now about one specific thing, everything's clear.

Comment: @qbait if you wanted to change your question, you should have edited your question. Deleting and reposting a slightly modified version is not cool.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I note it for the future.

Comment: @qbait and your question is still very poorly researched. Have you tried searching how to accomplish what you want? And after doing that, have you tried implement any of the multiple solutions? If so, what problems have you encountered?

Comment: Yea, I tried to achieve it with radial and linear gradient combination without the success.

Comment: @yivi what would you change in my question then?

Answer (score 19):

If you're talking about these questions:

- [The best practice to implement vertical list inside another vertical list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49719981/the-best-practice-to-implement-vertical-list-inside-another-vertical-list)
- [how to create instagram launcher icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49735437/how-to-create-instagram-launcher-icon)

...well, there's nothing you can do to fix these questions except take this one on the chin.

The first question you have is soliciting conversation and open-ended discussion, something we explicitly discourage on Stack Overflow.  It stands to reason that this kind of question would be downvoted.

The second question isn't *exactly* germane to what we do as programmers.  If you want to design a logo in a specific way, graphic designers would be a better ally than us.  Additionally, "how do I do this" is still far too broad of a question to pose.

Lesson learned: don't ask open-ended and broad questions.  Be sure to remember this lesson for the future.

Comment: Thank you @Makoto. Do you have any recommendation for the portal like stack overflow, but with the discussion about design patterns and best practices?

Comment: Nope - there's no such site here on the network.  You may be able to find a forum or a chat room if you're lucky.

Comment: I don't think "lesson learned" part is true so :) (second question re-posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736914/how-to-create-the-multicolor-gradient-background-as-xml... and still show absolutely no research effor)